# How to dynamically change json without reloading page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have this structure in my js code

```
    treeJSON = d3.json("/data", function (error, treeData) {
            // All code are here
            // making tree graph from json
            // and this is button 
            var button = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Move next</button>&nbsp;';
            $(function () {
              $('button').click(function () {
                //change json for whole project without reloading
              });
            });
```

I understang that I had to use AJAX thingy, but I can't found a way...

All new json you can get from "/data" url on server

I can't show all 400 lines of code, but I can say that it is simular to [this](http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033)

Comment: You should post the whole code. E.g. you don't show what you do with the `treeData`.

Comment: You can do something different: listen to a click => callback fetches data => callback draws a graph. If you need to autofetch for the first time you can programmatically emit a click on a button. It fits your logic better.

Comment: Seems like you are searching for something to manage the state for your app. there are million ways of doing this and depends of how you are going to structure and maintain your (web-)app. one possibility is redux as state-manager http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ .